# Echoed HTML Form does not call the onsubmit function

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a problem with my onsubmit:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='' onsubmit='return confirm(\"do you want to delete \" + {$array[0][1]} + \" \" +{$array[0][3]});'>
<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'>
</form>";
```

If I press my submit button, the confirm dialog wont open. The form gets submitted and my stuff gets deleted. I also tried to put the js in an external file but this also does not work.

Here is the Code from the external file:

```
function submitDeleteForm(prename, name) {
    confirm("Do you want to delete " + prename + " " + name + " ?")
}
```

And i just used return submitDeleteForm inside the onsubmit.

Rendered HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="apprentice" onsubmit="return confirm("Do you want to delete " + name+ " " +lastname);">
                            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">      
                          </form>
```

In the attempt with the external file, the HTML has the file in it, that means it does not fail at the import of the script.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: `I also tried to put the js in an external file but this also does not work.` This is definitely the best method to use; inline handlers are as bad as `eval`. Can you post your code from your external file attempt?

Comment: Also post the rendered (client side) html code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added the things you've asked for.

Comment: _“Rendered HTML: [...]”_ - that you have an issue with the quotes here should be obvious with one look, no? The best way to avoid this, is to not output larger parts of static HTML using echo to begin with, but only those parts that actually need to be dynamic - go read up on some syntax basics here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @LGSon added your things too

Comment: @CBroe after refreshing the page it changed in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have did some mistake while inserting double quotes in confirm(). Following code might work for you.

```
   echo "<form method='post' action='' onsubmit='return confirm(\"do you want to delete {$array[0][1]}  {$array[0][3]}\");'>
    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'>
    </form>";
```

Now let me tell you where exactly you are doing mistake.
lets consider

```
$array[0][1] = "Vijay1"
$array[0][3] = "Vijay3"
```

just for illustration purpose. For this input your code will generate following HTML code(rendered):

[image]

where vijay1 and vijay3 will become ***string variables of JavaScript*** instead of constant strings. It's a situation like, you're using a JavaScript string variable that has never been defined in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the rendered html? Before editing your post i'm definitely sure that's where your problem is, As per my experience, writing into parameters for js handlers break due to inability to escape string (such as double quote) as it is being server rendered in php.

Solution: encode your string data into base64 to safely encode string with escaped characters.

```
    $encodedString = base64_encode("do you want to delete $array[0][1] $array[0][1]?");
    onsubmit='return confirm($encodedString)'
```

as per docs about base64 string: This encoding is designed to make binary data survive transport through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean, such as mail bodies.

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php